# 22.04: Laptop microphone is sent to bluetooth headphones

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, headphones

If headphones are connected (wired or wireless), shouldn't they be the ONLY microphone in use (by default)?

When I connect bluetooth headphones (which have a microphone) to Ubuntu, my laptop microphone is also sent to the bluetooth headphones for no good reason - it's extremely distracting because the keyboard sounds can always be heard.

Is this the default behavior? And how to stop it when BT headphones are connected?
I'd like to be able to easily continue to use the laptop microphone, or the headphone jack microphone when a BT headset is not connected.

---

Setings > Sound > Input > Input Device
Shows both the BT microphone and internal microphone as both active, but provides no means to configure.

Comment: why *should* they be the only microphone in use? I always used to use my laptop mic, even though my headphones had one, because the headphones had much worse sound quality when mic is in use then not.

Comment: Because the keyboard and fan of the laptop are unwanted. If you don't like the headphone mic quality, you should be able to disable it.

Comment: The point is that no mic is automatically enabled or disabled. You should be able to choose, in each application, which mic you want to use. What application is recording using your laptop mic and playing it back to your headphones? That's the question you need to answer, and stop it from doing that. The OS doesn't use any mic or headphones; it just provides them to applications.